# How do I update my bare repo?

Tags: git

I created a bare repo to publish my repository, but I can't figure out how to update the bare repo with the current state of the main repository.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/2964397#2964397

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you want to duplicate all the objects from the main repo, do this inside the main repo:

```
git push --all <url-of-bare-repo>
```

Alternatively, do a fetch inside the bare repo:

```
git fetch <url-of-main-repo>
```

You cannot do a pull, because a pull wants to merge with `HEAD`, which a bare repo does not have.

You can add these as remotes to save yourself some typing in the future:

```
git remote add <whatever-name> <url-of-other-repo>
```

Then you can simply do

```
git push --all <whatever-name>
```

or

```
git fetch <whatever-name>
```

depending on what repo you're in. If `<whatever-name>` is `origin`, you can even leave it out altogether.

---

*Disclaimer*: I'm not a git guru. If I said something wrong, I'd like to be enlightened!

*Update*: Read the comments!

*Update 2022-10-10*: if you are fetching inside a bare git repo then you probably need to do a `git fetch origin master:master` otherwise your `git log` will not show the new commits. Use `git fetch origin *:*` to update all local branches. See comments for more info.

Comment: The push seems to work just fine, thx for the hint I think I will be able to integrate this into a hook or something similar.

Comment: When I did a `git-fetch --all` inside the bare repository, I didn't see updates I had made to the main repo, but when pushing them from the main repo with `git push --all <url-of-bare-repo>` I do see the updates in `git log`. Presumably there's a simple explanation for this - can someone explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't see"? I'm not sure how `git log` behaves in a bare repo; maybe try `git log --all`?

Comment: @Thomas - Yeah, by "didn't see" I mean `git log` doesn't show these updates in the bare repo. (Neither does `git log --all`, and neither does a working repo that created by cloning the bare repo - either via `git log --all` or by simply looking at new files that should show up there). It's a pretty quick test to see for yourself. Mostly I'm just curious what I'm missing.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. `git push` from the main repo pushes to the `master` branch in the bare repo, and does not concern itself with remote tracking branches. However, using `git fetch` only updates the remote tracking branch `origin/master`, and ignores the local branch `master`. So if the last thing you did was a `fetch`, then `git log origin/master` in the bare repo should show you the new commits.

Comment: If you clone the bare repo, the clone also receives the out-of-date `master` branch, but the remote ref is not cloned along with it. To get those changes, do `git pull origin remotes/origin/master` to pull changes from the remote branch *as it exists in the bare repo*.

Bottom line: it's probably best to always push, or always fetch, but not mix the two. Hope this makes some sense!

Comment: If your remotest repo is something like github, where you don't have access, can't run push, etc, you can do `git fetch -q origin master:master` inside your local bare repo. This will fetch the new stuff from github's master branch and update your local master branch to it.

Comment: @Altreus Indeed `master:master` is what is required to move HEAD forward to that of the remote repo. In my case because of a problem I couldn't connect to our bare repo anymore because git was missing. Until it gets solved I do a reverse tunnel and fetch to the central repo using: `git fetch ssh://localhost:8765/... master:master` and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Altreus If you want all branches then you can do `git fetch origin *:*`

Comment: @JBert's answer is what you're looking for

Comment: @deepdive I think it is `git fetch -p origin *:*` if you really want to have the same stuff on remote and on origin...

Answer (score 80):

I created a repository using the following command

`git clone --bare <remote_repo>`

Then I tried to update the bare clone using the answer by Thomas, but it didn't work for me.  To get the bare repository to update (which is what I think Let_Me_Be was asking), I had to create a mirror repository:

```
git clone --mirror <remote_repo>
```

Then I could run the following command in the mirrored repository to grab the main repository's updates:

```
git fetch --all
```

I came across this solution by reading [Mirror a Git Repository By Pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756747/mirror-a-git-repository-by-pulling/2756894#2756894)

Comment: To change an existing bare repo to mirror, all you need to do is add 2 lines to the git config file at <REPO>.git/config.  In the `[remote "origin"]` section, add `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` and `mirror = true`

Answer (score 67):

The only solution besides recreating with `git clone --mirror` is [from Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333302/994153):

```
git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

then you can `git fetch` and you'll see the updates.  The weird thing is that before this, even though there is a `remote` configured, it has no branches listed in `git branch -a`.

Comment: This really helped me out! Capistrano project/repo also uses this setting to allow one-liner `git remote update` to do the job.

Comment: If the remote has force-updated or deleted branches (and you want to reflect those changes), you may need to add `--force` and `--prune` respectively to the `git fetch` line.

Comment: This is 
a: the real answer
and
b: essential to convert a bare repo into something that works will with git worktrees


git clone --bare <remote> <local_path>/.bare;
cd <local_path>;
echo "gitdir: ./bare" > .git;
git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*';
git fetch;
git worktree add main;
cd main;
code .

Answer (score 52):

Assuming:

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/.../foo.git
```

Fetch with:

```
$ git --git-dir=foo.git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* --prune
```

Note: `--git-dir=foo.git` is not required if you `cd` to the directory first.

Comment: Although I'm not aware when that occurs, if `origin` is not defined, you can always replace the `origin` part with the path/url to your original repository.  e.g. `$ git --git-dir=foo.git fetch https://github.com/.../foo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 16):

After much messing around I've found that this works for me.

Once:

```
git clone --mirror ssh://git@source.address:2000/repo
git remote add remote_site ssh://git@remote_site.address/repo
git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

Everytime I want to sync:

```
cd /home/myhome/repo.git
git --bare fetch ssh://git@source.address:2000/repo
git  fetch ssh://git@source.address:2000/repo
git push --mirror remote_site
```

Comment: The third line (`git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'`) is the key. Good answer, thanks!

Comment: As @peterh said, the line `git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'` is the answer. After hitting this command, I can just `git fetch` and the repo syncs with the remote one.

Answer (score 3):

Add the bare repository as a remote repository, then use `git push`.

Comment: So if I want to do this without pushing I can't use a bare repository and use a symbolic link or something like that?

Comment: Pushing is the normal method for transferring repository contents to a bare repository, there is no need to avoid it.

Comment: You can't always push. For example, if the bare is in a private network, and the main repos is a public one (on GitHub, for exemple)

Answer (score 2):

For me this combination worked:

```
git remote add remote_site https://github.com/project/repo.git
git fetch -u remote_site +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
git fetch -u remote_site +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
git push --mirror
```

-u parameter for fetch was necessary, otherwise I get the error message:
"Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository" (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205680/4807875)