# git push as a sufficient backup solution?

Tags: git, push

I am starting to use git. 
I will be the only one using the repo. For backup purposes I want to regularly push my repo to a remote Server.

Using `git push` gives me the

```
git push error 'remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'.
```

To cope with this, I created a dummy branch on the remote location and checkout this branch.

Pushing into master now works fine.

I am a little worried since I can't see the actual files in my remote location.
Will this work as a backup system? When I switch to the master branch in my remote location all files are present.
Will the backup files be generated while pushing into a none active branch or will they be generated once the branch becomes active?

Hope you can help to clear things up.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather push to a bare repo (so, with *no* branch checked out), or even better (from a backup perspective), to a bundle:
See "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository/2129286#2129286)".

That way, you only need to create locally one file, that you can easily backup elsewhere.
(if you don't need the history, [`git archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) works too)

But if you have already a server for git repos, you need to reference on it a bare repo in order to avoid any push error message.

Comment: Note, to push to a bare repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382679/git-how-do-i-update-my-bare-repo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pushing to a bare repo will copy the refs from the .git-Folder for all branches? If I keep on doing it the way it is setup right now, I will only push the refs of the master-branch right?

Comment: @SirBlack: you can push only the current branch or all branches (and tags) at the same time. Basically, this is the same push than a non-bare repo.

Comment: So backing up the refs will save all the information to regenerate the files and the file structure?

Comment: @SirBlack: backing up the ref from the `.git`? No need: you just create a bare repo on the server, and push everything from your local repo to that bare repo. No need to select sub-directories within a `.git`.

Answer (score 1):

If your backup location has branch `backup` checked out, and you push to branch `master`, then when you come to backup files at your backup location (even if you were to do a `git pull` on your backup location) it would only backup the files that are in the currently checked out branch.

It **will** however, backup your .git folder which contains the refs to your other branches. So in theory, you are backing up the whole repo

Comment: More than just "in theory."  If you back up your .git folder, you _are_ backing up the entire repo.

Comment: @Karl, yeah... my poor choice of words. What I meant was it wouldn't backup those exact files but you would definitely be able to retrieve them from the refs

Answer (score -1):

Update (`git pull`) your remote branch, and you will see your changes.

Comment: @Jaitsu He has already pushed the branch to the remote server, and he's asking why he can't see it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, got mixed up with `hg up`