# Git - ssh server - files do not appear on server

Tags: git, ssh

After calling the `push` command files are not on the server.

On my local computer i have `test.git` directory.

I type:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "First commit"
git remote add origin user@server.com:/var/www/test.git
```

On serwer i created new directory `test.git`
inside `git init --bare --shared`

On local
`git push origin master`
And no new files appear on server
Even after `git push origin`

Any ideas? Maybe i forgot something?

Comment: You have created a bare repository (which you should). A bare repository does not have a working directory.

Comment: Which files are you talking about? The source files you added to your commit? You won't see them in a bare repository, since a bare repository only contains Git's internal “database”

Comment: To expand on the previous comment... The files in `server.com:/var/www/test.git/` should be the same (roughly) as those in the `.git/` directory in your local sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

You created your repo with --bare. That's mean you don't have a working directory. Try git log, you'll see your commit.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?....I'm hosting a git on ubuntu through ssh and I can see the commits with  git log but not the files.....what does --bare mean?....I didn't find much info on this

Comment: @JAF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare