# Git push from Raspberry Pi to Windows 10 via SSH

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh

I come to you with a (mabye very basic) question regarding git.

I have the following setup:

**- Raspberry Pi:** git respository created, added one file and commmitted it

**- Windows 10 PC:** git repository created, OpenSSH installed

Next thing I did was testing if can access via ssh in both directions which was working fine. I could connect from my Raspberry Pi to the Windows PC via ssh using my windows username and password. Now I wanted to push the one file committed on my Raspberry Pi to my repository on my windows pc. Therefore I used the following lines:

```
git remote add pc ssh://Username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Projects
git push pc master
```

Afterwards I get asked for the password where I enter my Windows Password.
As result I get the message:

```
fatal: '/Projects' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

This folder '/Projects' is on my Windows PC in the directory where I get when I connect via ssh. And if I run (locally) a "git status" in this folder I get the correct status.

I'd would be very thankful if you can help me, especially to understand where is
my thinking mistake. 
Can I use the windows username and password for git?
Do I need an extra ssh key for git?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Make sure to specify the absolute path on the remote like

Answer (score 0):

Remote git repo should be **bare**, so initialize it with `git init --bare`.
take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the absolute path like /home/user/projects