# How to download git repository from file system in GitLab CE?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have GitLab CE, but install is damaged and i can't start it. How i can download and open all repositories from file system?

UPDATE:

In gitlab.rb i have git repositories path and it is: `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/`, but there is what i've found:

```
FETCH_HEAD
HEAD
config
description
hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
hooks.old.1478620628
info
objects
refs
```

But there are no usual repository with source codes.

Comment: It’s configurable where the repositories are stored. See [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/repository_storage_paths.html). You should check what you have configured, and then go there. There should be a file structure of hopefully normal GIt repositories there (I don’t have GitLab, so I don’t know if that’s the case).

Comment: This looks like a repository. Have you actually tried to `find` your repositories?

Comment: Gitlab will store *bare* repositories, and this looks exactly like one. A bare repository will just hold the content of the `.git/`  folder, and will not have a checkout of your code.

Comment: So, where i can find real repository in case when my gitlab is broken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bare repository (you can see a pretty clear description in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare)).

It does not contain a checkout copy of your code, but you can use it as a regular target for `git clone`, `git fetch / pull`, and `git push` :

- If it is on the same computer as your working computer, you can clone it to a regular repository :

  ```
  # in your development directory :
  $ git clone /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<project-dir>
  ```
- If it lies on a computer which you can access through ssh, you can clone it through ssh :

  ```
  $ git clone user@server:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<project-dir>
  ```
- If your gitlab is down, and no other user can possibly modify this repo, it is safe to simply copy the directory, or make a tar archive :

  ```
  $ cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/
  $ tar -czf project.tgz project-dir/

  # then copy this tar archive anywhere you want,
  # extract it, and use it as above
  ```

Any of the above will also give you a backup of your current repo, which you can use to restore your gitlab afterwards.

Comment: This is still relevant in GitLab CE 14.x, the only difference is that the raw git repos are stored in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/##/##/##.git`. I was able to clone the `.git` directory directly.