# Git Setup on local Network

Tags: linux, windows, git

I have created local window server works perfectly, accessing urls from my browser. Also i have installed git, created a directory named "testgit" and run git init command, now directory have .git file also. I have tried to clone git repo from that local window server to my linux machine, i have run several commands, like

```
Server = win-3g0sosv9dle
directory = testgit
username = administrator


git clone git@win-3g0sosv9dle/testgit.git

git clone git@win-3g0sosv9dle/testgit

git clone administrator@win-3g0sosv9dle/testgit.git

git clone administrator@win-3g0sosv9dle/testgit/

git clone file://win-3g0sosv9dle/testgit/
```

i am unable to access

================================================

ok , i explain my scenario again,

we have set up a project test-git on local windows server, working fine, accessing from browser, like http://localip/test-git, have initialized git in it, like

git init

also shared on network , and accessible for every one, read and write.

want to access it from developer linux machine,

cloning into var/www/html folder but it gives error 403, repository not found,

what i have tried so far is,

for clonning,

git clone http://192.168.0.105/test-git/.git

git clone http://192.168.0.105:82/test-git/.git

difference in above methods is port number,

but it gives repository not found error, please help.

then the next step will be push/pull

please help where i am wrong

Comment: *"i am unable to access"* is not a useful problem statement or error message.

Comment: You really need to be more concise in your question. Maybe a git tutorial will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

To create a shared repo you will need to use `git init --bare --shared` :

check this question : [what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare)

or this article for more details: [setting-up-centralied-git-repository](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-centralied-git-repository/)