# Gitlab repositories file content location

Tags: git, file, ubuntu, repository, gitlab

So I am trying to backup my gitlab repository **FILES**. I looked in the `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` location and found the repos but the actual content of the repositories i.e.: the source codes are not there, just config files, HEAD files info, objects and refs folder etc.

can anyone tell me where on my server the actual files are stored?

I have lost the frontend ui of gitlab so cannot access it over the browser and need to download my source codes from the server.

Thanks.

Comment: These are `bare` repositories - to access the files stored within, you need to clone that path somewhere else.

Comment: i cant clone anything right now because i have issues in the server which is why i need to download the source code files manually. So where are the source code files stored then? Surely they must be stored somewhere? or am i missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "git init" and "git init --bare"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those *are* the actual files, in Git's internal form.

Remember, Git stores *every* version of *every* file saved in *every* commit.  To pull off this trick, it stores them in a form that is not useful to other (non-Git) programs, nor (directly) to you.

To extract files in a form that *is* useful to you and to other computer programs, you must `git checkout` some *particular commit*.  When you do this, you have Git populate what Git calls a *work-tree*, which is where you do your work.  Git fills in this work-tree (using Git's *index*, which I will mention but not explain here, as this gets a bit complicated) from the *one specific commit* you select.  Hence, the contents of this work-tree will depend on *which* commit you select.

A `--bare` repository is (defined as) one that has no work-tree, so that you cannot work in it.  This makes it suitable to receive incoming `git push` requests, which would otherwise potentially disturb the work someone might be doing.  Without a work-tree, no one can possibly work in it, so there is no work that can be disturbed.  But this also means you cannot select one commit and get its files in a work-tree, since there is no work-tree.

There are ways to view or extract files from each commit stored in a bare repository, but they are a bit tricky to use.  For instance, `git archive` can turn a commit into an archive (tar or zip) that you can extract elsewhere.  Remember that you'll generally get just *one commit at a time* when you ask for it.

Comment: awesome. Got it working now. Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain it mate :)