# Gogs access repository files to use lftp in an hook

Tags: git, hook, lftp, gogs

I'm using gogs as a git server on a Raspberry. I'd like to create a post-receive git hook to upload changes on my remote server (which I can access only via FTP). 
I think I can use lftp but the thing is that I don't know how to find my php files on my raspberry. When I go to my repository folder I don't have these files but some files like :  d81e2a2ed01b13b4117e59338b239137c81901

How can I proceed ?

Thanks, 
Thombou

Comment: What you see is a bare repository: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7861184/7976758), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/7976758).

Comment: OK thanks for the links. I guess I need to clone my repository in the hook and use lftp on this working directory