# Can't find pushed repo on git server

Tags: git, file, ssh, directory

I Cant seem to find the repo I pushed to the master branch on a virtual server I am renting. I can push and pull to it perfectly, but when I go into the server(via ssh) to view the files, I can't seem to find the project anywhere. I checked the branches directory and its  empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bare repo, which don't have an associated working directory, by convention.  See this [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html) and this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-to-use-git-bare-init-repository).

Comment: Wait, I still don't get why my local repo is a normal one and not a bare, but my server that I am pushing to is bare. How would I change it?

Comment: Yours is non-bare ("normal") so that you have a working directory; i.e. you'll have files to work on.  The one that you're pushing to is one that I assume you are treating as "central"; i.e. no one works in it but can push refs to. Why do you want to change that?