# Create a Git proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I need to push to a git repository from a server that has no access to it (it is blocked at IP level and my server's IP address is not in the allowed segment).

Let's assume I have a second server which has access to the git repository: would it be possible to set it up as a "git proxy" so that the first server can push into the second and this one into the main git repository?

I guess it is, and I have a slight idea about what I should search/do in order to set it up, but I'd like to know if there is a simple straightforward way to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Git over SSH, a standard [SSH tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_shell_tunneling) should let you push to your Git server without requiring a second Git repository. Something like this:

1. Establish an SSH connection from your blocked server to your non-blocked server that includes a tunnel to your target Git server:

   ```
   ssh non.blocked.server -L 2222:git-host.com:22
   ```
2. In a separate terminal, while the SSH connection is still active, issue Git commands targeting `localhost:2222`; these will be tunnelled through the SSH connection and be sent to your Git host while appearing to originate from your non-blocked server:

   ```
   git ls-remote localhost:2222/some/repo.git
   ```

If you're using HTTPS instead, look into HTTP proxies to do the same thing.

And finally, you could set up your non-blocked server as a Git remote of your blocked server. Then you could `git push` from the blocked server to the non-blocked server, and then `git push` again from the non-blocked server to the Git host. Note that in this case you probably want to [create a bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-to-use-git-bare-init-repository) on the non-blocked host instead of a regular repository.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I'm using HTTPS so I'll look for what you recommended.