# GIT Remote Repo Setup

Tags: git

I am trying to get my GIT Remote working. On my Windows local machine GIT remote is setup like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test [master]> git remote
develop
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test [master]> git remote -v
 develop ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/ (fetch)
 develop ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/ (push)
```

I have GIT installed on the linux server that where the application will live. What do I have to setup on Windows local machine and/or linux server in order to get code from my local machine changes to be pushed on the linux server?

This is the command I am running on my windows local machine to push changes on the linux server:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test [master]> git push develop master
Warning: Permanently added 'develop.livm.net,192.168.19.70' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@develop.livm.net's password:
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 358 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/
1527464..04f0441  master -> master
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test [master]>
```

I do not see the code changes on the linux server master branch after I run this command from my windows local machine. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

On my remote machine the project is here:

```
/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/
```

and there is a .git folder in there like this:

```
/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git
```

Is the project supposed to be inside .git folder or the way I currently have it setup?

Comment: Check inside the .git folder on your remote machine. Is the project directory in there?

If it is try changing your remote to ```ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/```

Comment: On my remote machine the project is here: /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/ and there is a .git folder in there like this: /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git       Is the project supposed to be inside .git folder or the way I currently have it setup?

Comment: Were you able clone from that URL? or did you add it as remote after cloning?

Comment: I have used git in the past as a developer. But now I am learning to configure git and that is what I am not understanding. So I am not sure what I did when I first did this setup, cloning from url or remote cloning. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the project from your linux server, use this path:

`git clone ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/`

to add it as a remote to your current project: try

`git remote add new_develop ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/`

Comment: When I do this procedure:git add testgit_windows.php   git commit -m "testing push to development server"   git push develop master   
root@develop.livm.net's password:
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 357 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/
   64128ef..33f3c84  master -> master    my local code changes are NOT in the remote linux server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also when I create a new file on the linux remote server and then I try to locally pull new file it does not give me the new file: C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master]> git pull develop master
Warning: Permanently added 'develop.livm.net,192.168.19.70' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@develop.livm.net's password:
From ssh://develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.  Please help.

Comment: Are you on the master branch in the remote git repo?

When you say you create a file in the remote, do you also add it and commit it?

Comment: On my remote machine here is some commands I just ran so you can see: [root@develop test]# pwd
/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test
[root@develop test]# ls
testgit_new.php  testgit_windows.php
[root@develop test]# git branch
* master
[root@develop test]# git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
[root@develop test]# So maybe I did not do something on the remote machine?

Comment: Did you create a bare repository?

Comment: On the remote machine I created a bare repository like this: [root@develop test]# pwd
/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test [root@develop test]# git init --bare .

Comment: Here is what in /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test 
[root@develop test]# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 branches
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     66 Nov  7 12:37 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     73 Nov  7 12:37 description
drwxr-xr-x 8 root   root   4096 Nov  5 11:53 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     23 Nov  7 12:37 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 info
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 objects
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 refs

Comment: This is getting too difficult to troubleshoot in comments, I suggest you restart the process and list what tutorial/instructions you are following in a new question.

But also check other answers on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-do-you-use-git-bare-init-repository

If you can't figure out try to reach out to me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add a hook in my git directory. Now my local and remote GIT works great! I used post-update hook:

```
[root@develop hooks]# more post-update
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to prepare a packed repository for use over
# dumb transports.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-update".
# exec git update-server-info

GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/websiteactualwebdir git checkout -f
```

I found and followed these two tutorials to guide me on this: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/

I needed to learn a bit more about bare versus regular repositories and hooks, which is what I originally missed.