# Git repository difference

Tags: git, github

I have seen git repository in two different ways:

### Case I:

I am creating my own git repository using commands as (`git init followed by git add and git commit`). And here if see my directory contains files/folder with sources and that of .git directory.

### Case II:

In another case where i am seeing another git repository with folders something like (branches/, description, hooks/, objects/, refs/, config, HEAD, info/, packed-refs).

Can someone please let me know how to create the git repository as mentioned in case II?

Comment: Your description sounds like a so-called "bare" repository. The very short description of a bare repository is that it is one with no work-tree, so that no one can work in it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-do-you-use-git-bare-init-repository and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one for more.

Answer (score 0):

Case II is called 'bare' repository. It can represent e.g. project intended to be hosted on some site or e.g. mirror of other git repository.

To create it, simply:

```
$ git init --bare
```

Switch `--bare` will instruct `git` to NOT create working directory/tree, and will put content of `.git` dir in current dir. Instead of `--bare` you can use also `--mirror <url>` to set up mirror of other `git` repo (there are some configuration differences between bare and mirror - look into file `config` to learn more).