# What is the use of git bare repositories?

Tags: git, git-bare

On the remote machine I create a bare repository with the following command:

```
git init --bare $HOME/bare/My-Repo
```

On my local machine I clone a repo (but **not** the one that I have created on the remote machine):

```
git clone ssh://something.com/My-Repo
```

On my local machine, in the repository that I have just cloned, I create a "reference" to the above mentioned bare repository located on the remote machine:

```
git remote add my_remote ssh://remote.com/${USER}/bare/My-Repo
```

I do not know if it is relevant to my question but I also do the following stuff in my local repository:

```
git config remote.my_remote /some/path/git-receive-pack
git config remote.my_remote /some/path/git-upload-pack
```

Now, I can push from the local repository to the bare repository on the remote machine:

```
git push my_remote master
```

Now, the idea is that we create another repository on the remote machine which should take some content from the bare repository. I create this repo by executing something like this on the remote machine:

```
some_script.sh $HOME/bare/My-Repo $HOME/My-Repo
```

Now, I do some changes in the `$HOME/My-Repo` on the remote machine (please note that it is not the **bare** repository), then I `git add` and `git commit` and after that I push:

```
git push origin my-dev-branch
```

As a result I push to the bare repository (which is located on the same remote machine). After that I go to my local machine and "take" the changes from the remote machine (from the bare repository):

```
git fetch my_remote
git checkout -b my-dev-branch my_remote/my-dev-branch
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

So, my questions are: Why do we need this bare repository? Why can't we just have one remote repository and directly exchange content between the local and remote repositories? Or, alternatively, why can't we just `rsync`  (or `scp`) the local repository to and from the remote machine?

**ADDED**

This is why I ask the question instead of googling. I have googled my question and the first link is here: http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/

I read there:

> Repositories created with the git init command are called working
>   directories. In the top level folder of the repository you will find
>   two things:
>   A .git subfolder with all the git related revision history of your
>   repo A working tree, or checked out copies of your project files.
>   Repositories created with git init --bare are called bare repos. They
>   are structured a bit differently from working directories. First off,
>   they contain no working or checked out copy of your source files. And
>   second, bare repos store git revision history of your repo in the root
>   folder of your repository instead of in a .git subfolder. Note… bare
>   repositories are customarily given a .git extension.

So, now to understand that I need to know:

1. What is "revision history"?
2. What is "working tree"?
3. What is "checked out copies"?

And this is just the first section. I know, that the response would be: Go and read the git tutorial or introduction to git. Well I did it. The first problem with it is that the use of terms is "circular". Term A is expressed through term B and term B is expressed through term A. Second, I do not have time to read a book just to find an answer on my question. Third, I am 100% sure that the answer on my question can be expressed in simple terms. It is actually trivial.

Comment: Almost any question that I ask about git gets closed and down voted and it does not happen with my questions about other topics. Is it a bad thing to ask about git? Git is something that you need to read about using tutorials and not asking questions? Well I know that there are many tutorial but I just do not understand them because I am probably not smart enough to grasp the extremely complex concepts of git.

Comment: *"Is it a bad thing to ask about git?"* - no, there are many well received [tag:git] questions. But this one is very broad; you asked three questions in the first draft alone. Given that you don't know the answer, it's unclear why you're certain that it is trivial and, as you identify, there are a few related concepts to understand. There are many existing resources, and if you *"do not have time"* you are not doing the research required before asking. For example, have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7632454/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the question that you link is not the same as mine. The user asking there how to push to bare repository. In my case I know how to do it.

Comment: I didn't say it was, I'm not voting to close as duplicate. But the answers there do talk about what a bare repo is, and my point is still that there are existing resources. If you don't have time for initial research, you shouldn't be expecting others to spend the time synthesising for you. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I never said that I do not have time for initial research, I said that now I do not have time to read the full tutorial or even introduction. Anyway, it can be applied to any question: Why do you ask questions? Don't you have time to find the answers alone? Why do you expect others to waste their time on you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your main question boils down to this: *why do we need an intermediary bare repository to sync between two Git repositories?*

In your concrete example you have a local Git repository, let's call it X, and two remote repositories, a bare one let's call it B, and a non-bare one, let's call it Y.

At this point I hope you see that X and Y could be anywhere. They could both be local, or they could both be remote, on the same server as B. It doesn't matter where they are, what matters is that you want to sync between them, and for that you need B, somewhere, anywhere. And your question is *why*?

First of all, you don't really *need* B in the middle. It's recommended, and the default behaviors will guide you in this direction.

Why is it recommended to have a bare repo between repositories?
The answer has to do with *working trees*.
The working tree is where you have the files you work on.
The Git repository of a working tree is inside the `.git` subdirectory.
The Git commands you execute inside the working tree communicate with the Git repository, query its content, and make comparisons with the content you have in the working tree.
A bare repository is like the `.git` directory alone, without a working tree.

To demystify bare repositories, try this to see the difference between a bare and non-bare repo:

```
$ cd /tmp/
$ git init --bare bare.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/bare.git/
$ git init regular
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/regular/.git/
$ diff -r bare.git/ regular/.git/
diff -r bare.git/config regular/.git/config
4c4,5
<   bare = true
---
>   bare = false
>   logallrefupdates = true
```

Technically, the difference is a matter of a few configuration flags.
I could move the `bare.git` directory to any directory in the filesystem, rename it to `.git`, edit the `config` file and voila, I will have converted a bare repository a regular one.

Back to the question: why is it recommended to have a bare repository between two non-bare repositories that want to sync with each other?
By default, Git forbids pushing to a non-bare repository.
What if it didn't?
If `git push` will update the content of the `.git` of the remote,
what should happen to the corresponding working tree?
A lot of questions would follow:

- What is the current branch of the working tree? If the push didn't change that branch, then everything is fine.
- What should happen if the push affected the current branch of the working tree? Should Git update the working tree?

  - If the working tree is not clean, it cannot be safely updated. Uncommitted changes can get lost.
  - Even if the working tree is clean, there can be conflicts if there are changes to `.gitignore`, or if the history of the branch was re-written with force push.
  - If we don't update the working tree, it will be out of sync with the repository, so `git status` would report modifications that should not be committed.

Does this sound complicated and confusing? That's because it is.
And it's the reason why pushing to non-bare repository is not allowed by default. You [*can*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/how-to-push-to-a-non-bare-git-repository) do it if you really want, it *can* be reasonably safe if you consistently keep clean the working tree of the repo you push to, but it would be error-prone (you might forget), and nobody needs such uncertainty and mental burden. It's really best to just use a bare repository in between.