# how to git an existing project on a server

Tags: git

I do have an existing project on my internet server. now i decided to start git this.
what i have to do to make a clean git out of it?
What i tried / done so far on the server:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial"
```

than on locale machine:

```
git pull ssh://user@server/project
...
fatal: '/project' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

what are the steps i have to do?

thanks...

Comment: You clone, not pull.

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: i did ```git init``` locally also. if not, would ```git pull...``` work? did i have to ```push``` before i can ```pull```?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer as you followed up with questions..

First check that your server repository is initialised as a git repository.

Then check that the path you have provided git is pointing to your server repository.

As @matt pointed out, use `git clone ssh://user@server/project` to make a local copy of the remote repo.

This is simpler (and the standard method) than initialising a local git repo, adding the remote url and pulling.

Hint: If you're not working inside the repository in the remote server (ie all distributed work will take place on machines other than the server) then it makes sense to use a bare repository, see this link:

[How do you use "git --bare init" repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-do-you-use-git-bare-init-repository)

Comment: Thx to you and matt. It's running now!

Comment: now i cloned and made some changes on master, commitet them and successfully pulled them to my clone. now i added a new file locally but when i push that commited changes i got:
```remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
fatal: Unable to create '.../.git/packed-refs.lock': Permission denied
error: failed to run pack-refs
To ssh://...
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://...'
```

Comment: I'm new to answering questions but I think your comment merits a separate question. Also - did you try looking for an answer? A very quick search gave this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab

Comment: thx, yes i searched for that problem but i cant change usergroud on my local windows system. and when i change that on the runing live remote server maybe something wont work than. little bit confused.