# How do I properly configure a bare repository for git fetch?

Tags: git

(This question builds on [How do I update my bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382679/git-how-do-i-update-my-bare-repo) and [git fetch doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches).)

I've cloned a bare repository from GitHub, the idea being that:

- Developers use GitHub, and push to Github.
- On the server, the above-mentioned bare repo fetches from GitHub (say, `/var/repo/my_repo`)
- The bare repo is cloned to one or more "document root" locations for web serving to facilitate various checkouts of the codebase. So, `/var/www/my_repo_live` and `/var/www/my_repo_dev` are both non-bare clones of `/var/repo/my_repo` but have different branches or tags checked out for serving.

I seem to have run into some complexities—from the `git clone` [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

- When `--bare` is used, "the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin/`."
- "Neither remote-tracking branches nor the related configuration variables are created."

This makes sense: since you're not going to do editing in a bare repository, you don't need to separate remote tracking from local tracking branches. But, then:

- How *are* you supposed to fetch?
- Given that remote branch heads are copied directly to the corresponding local branch heads, how do you set up your `remote.$remote_name.fetch` refspec? Should it just be `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`?

**P.S.** I am separating `/var/repo/my_repo` from the document root repos for permission reasons. I don't want publicly-facing, `www-data` processes to have access to the repository that's linked to GitHub. Is this overkill? Regardless of whether it's overkill, I would still like to know to properly manage fetching with a bare repo.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079064/2536029

Comment: @mnagel: Nope! Hadn't seen that. Thank you. I will check out mirror repos. Had never heard of them. In the mean time, I'm just using `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` in `.git/config` under my repo (or directly with `git fetch`) to get the results I'm looking for. I wonder what's right ~conceptually~.