# How to mirror a git repository safely?

Tags: git

I want to mirror some git repositories with a background job. `git clone --mirror` and `git remote update` won't preserve objects that were unreferenced with a forced push, but I want to keep those too in case of a hack. Are there any tools to perform safe git mirrors?

Comment: is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756747/mirror-a-git-repository-by-pulling

Comment: As said in my question, git would delete commits that are unreferenced with `git push --force`, wouldn't it? Is there a difference in the behavior of `git remote update` and `git fetch` in this regard?

Comment: If you care about unreferenced objects, public `git` APIs most likely won't cut it for you. In that case, why not just `rsync` the repo?

Comment: Because for most repositories, like on GitHub, you don't have rsync access.

Comment: for public repos, you wont get a "safe" backup by your definition then. if it's specifically a public hosting service like github, you can use a combination of hooks and your own backup server to keep incremental backups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it would be tedious short of a shell script, if you have access to the remote repository then you could perform:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

This will list the unreferenced commits and you can then create a branch for each one:

```
git branch <branch-for-commit> <commit>
```

At this point nothing is unreferenced and the clone won't gc/lose anything.  After that, if you chose, you can delete the branches as in [Delete Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610669/1286639)

Like this:

```
git fsck --lost-found | \
  grep dangling | \
  awk '{ system ("git branch" " br-" $3 " " $3); }'
```

to retain dangling commits and blobs. Then, after the clone,

```
git branch -a | grep "br-" | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: this will only work on a local repository. there is no way to run `git fsck` on a remote repository like github.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said 'if you have access to the remote repository'.

Answer (score 3):

After re-reading the question and the provided answers I'm sure I misinterpreted the poster's intent.

Now I think what's needed is enabling [the reflog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) in the destination repository, by setting the `core.logAllRefUpdates` in it to `true`, and possibly tuning the associated parameters controlling the reflog expiration policy (grep the [`git-config` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for the world "reflog").  This will log all "drastic" refs repositions allowing to rollback forced pushes or the like.

Note that still the only true protecting against, say you say, "hacking", or any other kind of loss is having secured *offsite* backups, so what I proposed in my first answer, I think, still holds.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much of a security issue. If you accidentally pushed a password or something, it is possible to amend your commit and force push the new commit. Afterwards git will not allow any access to the first commit.

If you really need those commits you need access to the file system and use something like `rsync` to fetch everything. - But be aware that git from time to time is doing some garbage collection, hence old unreferenced commits get actually lost.

Comment: what?  git will merrily let you access the original commit; it's now probably called `@{1}`.

Comment: Only if that commit is in the local repository. It will not let you access any unreferenced commit in a remote repository.

Comment: oh, i see what you mean.  i don't think that's meant as a _security_ measure, though.  it's just assumed to be garbage if it's not accessible via a branch or tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could employ two-phase backups:

1. `git fetch <remote> +refs/*:refs/*` to update a bare mirror repository.

   `git gc` to possibly "normalize" its contents.
2. [`rdiff-backup`](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) the result to another directory, which will contain the last backed up version plus a collection of binary diff files which could be used to reconstruct any previous backup.

This way you could have a versioned history of your backup snapshots. Since `rdiff-backups` allows to ditch old snapshots, you could story only as many snapshots as you see fit.

The drawback is the waste of disk space:

- `rdiff-backup` will make a true copy of the source directory; no file will be shared.
- AFAIK, Git internals dealing with pack files do not support something like the `--rsyncable` command-line option of the `gzip` program, so the deltas generated by `rdiff-backup` might be big. On the other hand, in a typical Git repo any pack file should only ever be appended, not rewritten, so I might be barking on a wrong tree here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fetching into a repo you control, there are [`gc` config items](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_variables) to control every aspect of what gets removed and when; `git remote update` (and everything else) *will* preserve unreferenced objects as long as you like.  Anyone with administrative access can publish unreferenced objects by tagging them.

So to mirror a repo safely, if you have administrative control over it just set up a hook to forward incoming pushes to a backup repo that never expires.  Otherwise, keying off receipt of a commit notice will ensure you'll remember everything you ever *could* have seen.

Answer (score 1):

Methinks one of the commenters has it right: rsync or equivalent is your only friend, irrespective of the fact that it's not an option for e.g. Github.

See this (admittedly old) thread:

http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/8/28/256180/thread

Quoting one of the messages:

> It has nothing to do with Linux development practices.  There are 
>   fundamental reasons why we don't fetch hooks:
>
> - they are *not* part of the repository; just look at the 
>     .gitattributes-in-the-index-but-not-worktree issue to find out why,
> - it is *private* data, just like the config.  The client has *no 
>     business* to read them, let alone fetch them,
> - if you have the hooks on different machines, chances are that you need a 
>     mechanism to update the hooks... This naturally suggests putting the 
>     hooks into their own branch.
>
> Probably there are way more reasons not to allow such a thing as fetching 
>   hooks.

So... Putting the hooks in their own repo is a good solution if you want to deploy them in multiple locations, but besides that there isn't much you can do insofar as I'm aware for all sorts of objects in a repo...

(credits for that link goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154010/417194)

For github in particular, there *might* be workarounds with github-services or web hooks.