# Why do I get an error when I use the git mirror command?

Tags: git, github, remote-repository, git-mirror

I'm having trouble mirroring my repository. The following commands works:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/my_username/my-repo.git
cd my-repo
```

There is another repository which is empty that I want mirrored. That repository is owned by another person but I have access to it as I can see it in my GitHub account.

When I execute the following command, I get an error:

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/their-username/their-repo

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository ‘https://github.com/their-username/their-repo/’ not found
```

Repositories:

1. https://github.com/my-username/my-repo (This is my repo which has my username)
2. https://github.com/their-username/their-repo (This is their repo which has their username)

I am trying to mirror 1 into 2. I can successfully clone both repositories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mirror a git repository safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003037/how-to-mirror-a-git-repository-safely)

Answer (score 0):

Git has mirror functionality built right into it

From your repo

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/their-username/their-repo
```

Note that this will completely overwrite their repo so you should make sure that they are OK with this.

Comment: Thanks but I already know that I need to use the mirror command. The problem is I don't know why I'm getting an error when I use it.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

I had **read-only** access and not **read-write access.** I emailed my organistaion and they changed this and it worked.