# Mirroring certain files/directories of a git repository

Tags: git, github

I'd like to maintain a mirror version of [Twitter's Bootsrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for my development environment. Now I'm not interested in polluting my work directory with all the contents of Bootstrap. I rather only want to mirror certain directories in their appropriate places. Consider this example:

```
./myComputer              github.com/twbs/bootstrap
 + assets                 |
   + js                   |
   | + lib                |     
   |   + bootstrap   <--- + js/*
   + css                  |
   | + lib                |
   |   + bootstrap   <--- + less/*
   + fonts           <--- + fonts/*
```

This should be a basic downstream mirror. I don't expect git to keep track of my changes I make locally. I just want it to apply patches on a regular base. I've read [Mirror a git repository by pulling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756747/mirror-a-git-repository-by-pulling), but this method doesn't allow me to only pick certain direcotries to sync.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to:

- `git fetch upstream`
  (with '`upstream`' being a remote name for the github bootstrap repo)
  That fetches everything, but keep it in the remote namespace "`remotes/upstream`"
- merge the folders that you want (as in "[How do I merge a sub directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190916/6309)"), with `git read-tree`.